# React Firebase onSnapshot returning null for mapping function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I seem to be getting the error ***"filtered.map is not a function"*** and I'm assuming its because of my **onSnapshot** returning a null because it hasn't fired yet to pull the data, (aka make it available) to be used to filter inside my component.

If I change the .map from **filtered** useState to my useState **knives** then I can get the data and no error and when I change it back I can then use my filter component without any issues.

**Parent Component:**

```
function KnifesComponent() {
  const knifeCollection = collection(db, "knives");
  const [knives, setKnives] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
      const sub = onSnapshot(knifeCollection, (snapshot) => {
        setKnives(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        setFiltered(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        const TotalSkins = snapshot.size;
        setCount(TotalSkins);
      });
      return () => {
        sub();
      }
  }, []);

  const rarities = {
    Exclusive: "Rarity_Exclusive.png",
    Ultra: "Rarity_Ultra.png",
    Premium: "Rarity_Premium.png",
    Deluxe: "Rarity_Deluxe.png",
  };  

  return (
    <div className="collection">
      <h2 className="section-heading">
        Knives <div className="count">({count})</div>
        <Filter
          skins={knives}
          setFiltered={setFiltered}
          activeFilter={activeFilter}
          setActiveFilter={setActiveFilter}
        />
      </h2>
        {filtered.map((skin) => {
          return (
            <div
              layout
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
              className="skin-box"
              key={skin.id}
            >
              <div className="skin-rarity">
                <Image src={require(`../../public/${rarities[skin.rarity]}`)} />
              </div>
              <h4>{skin.name}</h4>
              <div className="skin-value">
                <p>{skin.value}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      <div className="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Filter Component:**

```
function Filter({ setActiveFilter, activeFilter, setFiltered, skins }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeFilter === "") {
      setFiltered("");
      return;
    }
    const filtered = skins.filter((skin) => skin.rarity.includes(activeFilter));
    console.log(filtered)
    setFiltered(filtered);
  }, [activeFilter]);

  return (
    <div className="filter-container">
      <button
        className={activeFilter === [] ? "active" : ""}
        onClick={() => setActiveFilter([])}
      >
        All
      </button>
      <button
        className={activeFilter === "Ultra" ? "active ultra" : "ultra"}
        onClick={() => setActiveFilter("Ultra")}
      >
        Ultra
      </button>
      <button
        className={
          activeFilter === "Exclusive" ? "active exclusive" : "exclusive"
        }
        onClick={() => setActiveFilter("Exclusive")}
      >
        Exclusive
      </button>
      <button
        className={activeFilter === "Premium" ? "active premium" : "premium"}
        onClick={() => setActiveFilter("Premium")}
      >
        Premium
      </button>
      <button
        className={activeFilter === "Deluxe" ? "active deluxe" : "deluxe"}
        onClick={() => setActiveFilter("Deluxe")}
      >
        Deluxe
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to change to always have the array filled for the filter to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one source of problems:

```
if (activeFilter === "") {
  setFiltered("");
  return;
}
```

You're setting the `filtered` state variable to an empty string, but all other code (including when you declare `filtered` in `useState` assumes that it is an array.

My guess is that you want to do:

```
if (activeFilter === "") {
  setFiltered([]);
  return;
}
```

Comment: omw you are right - oversight from me  yes it should be an array and that did fix the problem of it returning a null

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was fixed I failed to see I need to update my setFiltered to an array instead of a empty string

```
if (activeFilter === "") {
  setFiltered("");
  return;
}
```

to

```
if (activeFilter === "") {
  setFiltered([]);
  return;
}
```